# Forbid BibLaTeX to break URLs at hyphens

Tags: biblatex, hyphenation, urls, url

By default, BibLaTeX will happily break lines at hyphens in URLs:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{main.bib}
@online{entry,
  title = {Title},
  subtitle = {Subtitle},
  author = {Doe, John},
  url = {http://some-quite-long-url-that-contains-hyphens},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{main.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: result of typesetting the above code with pdfLaTeX]

This can easily lead to confusion: was the hyphen added as a part of hyphenation, or is it a meaningful part of the URL? Therefore, I would like to forbid the hyphenation of URLs at hyphens.

BibLaTeX uses the `url` package, which does not break URLs at hyphens by default, and I see no mention about this behavior in the BibLaTeX documentation.

Comment: if you forbid the break there, the url can't break at all (or only after the //) and this will lead to bad spacing. Imho in the bibliography it is better to accept more break places, even if this leads to slightly confusing urls.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer In this MWE, I agree. However, there is often plenty `/` in the URLs and DOIs, which may be considered better line break points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`biblatex` has its own URL setup in [`\biburlsetup` (ll. 285-324 of `biblatex.def` in v3.16)](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/ca032db14c25fcad84a75ce5f43ba59c39ac69f2/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L285-L324). The default `\biburlsetup` contains `\def\UrlBigBreaks{\do\:\do\-}%` and so explicitly allows line breaks at hyphens. We can undo that by changing `\UrlBigBreaks` in `\appto\biburlsetup`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\appto\biburlsetup{%
  \def\UrlBigBreaks{\do\:}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{entry,
  title    = {Title},
  subtitle = {Subtitle},
  author   = {Doe, John},
  url      = {http://some-quite-long-url-that-contains-hyphens},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: No line break in long URL.]

Of course not allowing to break URLs at hyphens can make many 'modern' URLs extremely hard to break at all. If a URL is typeset in a different font than the main text, most readers are probably warned that any hyphens appearing in the URL are real and not caused by hyphenation.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `\do\-` to `\UrlNoBreaks`:

```
\def\UrlNoBreaks{\do\-\do\(\do\[\do\{\do\<}%
```

But as you can see from the example below in this way the url can not break and the result is ugly:

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{main.bib}
 @online{entry,
  title = {Title},
  subtitle = {Subtitle},
  author = {Doe, John},
  url = {http://some-quite-long-url-that-contains-hyphens},
 }
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{main.bib}

\def\UrlNoBreaks{\do\-\do\(\do\[\do\{\do\<}%

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
 \nocite{*}
 \printbibliography
\end{document}
```